# How to share a message in google Plus on multiple friends wall in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, google-api, google-plus, share

I'm trying to share a url with message on mutiple friends wall, in the current method I can choose friends while sharing, I was wondering if there is any way to predefine the friendlist to which the share should be posted. This is my current implementation as per google doc

```
- (IBAction) didTapShare: (id)sender 
{
   {
            [GPPShare sharedInstance].delegate = self;
            id<GPPShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] shareDialog];

            [shareBuilder setURLToShare:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dummy.com"]];
            [shareBuilder setTitle:@"Some title" description:@"Some description" thumbnailURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dummy.com/image"]];
            [shareBuilder setContentDeepLinkID:@"share"];
            [shareBuilder open];
        }
}

- (void)finishedSharing:(BOOL)shared
 {
    NSString *text = shared ? @"Success" : @"Canceled";
    NSLog(@"%@",text);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: [shareBuilder setTitle:@"jpt"
               description:@"What the hell"
              thumbnailURL:[NSURL URLWithString:Str_KoolkatPic]];
    [shareBuilder setContentDeepLinkID:kClientID];

    [shareBuilder open];

It doesnt work on me does that work on your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Google+ Sign-In, you can include people in the share list using something like

```
  [shareBuilder setPreselectedPeopleIDs:@[@"106189723444098348646",@"109813896768294978296"]];
```

before the line

```
  [shareBuilder open];
```

More details at https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/prefill#prefill_the_recipients_of_a_post

Comment: I used id<GPPNativeShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] nativeShareDialog] for using setPreselectedPeopleIDs but I am getting this error, initializing __Stron id<GPPNativeShareBuilder> with an expression of incompatible type id<GPPShareBuilder> any idea?

Comment: It isn't easy to read the code fragment in the comment. Try updating the original question with the code you're now using or post a new question.

Comment: Its seems that I had old sdk when I downloaded the new sdk it was working fine. Thanks.